# Hosting discussion forums on Windows 2008 Server / IIS, what software to use?

Tags: untagged

A plan to look into hosting discussion forums related to our product, on our own servers, has arisen, and I can't seem to find any pure .NET or Windows-based discussion forums. Since we're a pure Windows-based company, installing something that requires MySQL or Linux is going to require administration knowledge we don't currently have.

What are our options?

Every site I find that shows how to set up discussion forums on IIS involves just taking one of the many LAMP-based ones and tweaking IIS to run PHP or similar to run it.

Isn't there a .NET-based discussion forum software?

Free or not doesn't matter at this stage, right now we're just looking for options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is  [Web-Wiz forums](http://www.webwiz.co.uk/web-wiz-forums/) software.

It is written in classic-ASP and uses SQL Server (latest version is 9.70 - version 9.06 was definitely SQL2000 compatible). There is a free version (I think it just requires advertising/promoting their software) and the paid version is affordable (was £300 but looks like you could get a single website licence for £60 now).

I have supported the software, ended up hosting it, migrated it onto a new server, upgraded the forums (in one step from about version 4 or 5 to 9.06) and also customised some features to provide some client specific requirements. The installation I was looking after was popular with more than 100,000 registered members, a few hundred thousand posts (old posts removed after a certain time).

I think it competes very well with all the common php/MySQL forums I've seen. It works well "out of the box", is customisable (without having to modify code) and I had good experiences with their support (via their forums) for upgrades and even figuring out how to do something with customised code.

Answer (score 0):

http://community.zimbra.com/

Zimbra can be traced back to Telligent Systems, who produced the ASP.NET-based Community Server suite (circa 2005) which itself had its roots from ASP.NET Forums v1.